# Importing my packages and my methods inside my code?

Tags: java

I am getting this error that the method is not defined for my lab06 class, eventhough I imported it:
[image: 1]

You can see here that the class MyMethods is inside the package MyPackage:
[image: 2]

Can anyone tell me why is this not compiling? MyPackage folder (which contains MyMethods files) and lab06 class files are inside the lab06 folder. I would've provided you guys with more pictures but my 'reputation' isn't high enough for that kind of godly gesture.

The problem solves itself if I type MyMethods.spaceCount instead of spaceCount, but it will be a pain to write that in front of every single method I create. Importing should've solved this issue shouldn't it? At least that's what I've seen before.

Comment: Please post the actual code in the question rather than a picture.

Comment: I didn' want to post a long thread, will do that next time, thanks.

Comment: And post code *inside* the question. All questions need to be self-contained.

Answer (score 4):

To import static methods so that they don't need a class prefix, you have to use the `static` keyword in your import:

```
import static MyPackage.MyMethods.*;
```

Comment: Learnt something new today. Thanks.

Comment: @Carlton It's not used very often, because it's only really useful on small projects. Larger projects would suffer because it's not clear what class the method came from.

Comment: @4castle So its better to do it the classical way i.e **SomeClass.staticMethod()** ?